# 2.8 Sculpting Resolution?

Tags: sculpting, resolution

Newbie sculpting question. When using dynotopo, it looks like a resolution of 10 is a low resolution? Am I understanding this correctly? If so, what number would be considered high resolution for final character detail? Cheers!

Comment: Which method detail size mode do you ask about, Constant or Relative, or Brush? I don't think there's any certain numbers which can be "ideal for character" or "perfect for organic creature". It all depends on project, artistic needs etc.

Comment: Sorry I'm using "subdivide collapse" and "constant detail." Is it more just about watching the Verts, Tris?

Comment: Usually sculpting is done without worrying about polygons count as the details are meant to be baked  into normal map to be used withh lowpoly mesh in the end app. Although it is not always the case, sometimes sculpting is done with as much details as possible and as few polygons as reasonable to have. Again, so far this question is too broad. What's the purpose of the mesh created with dyntopo?

Answer (score 4):

The size used by [dynamic topology](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/adaptive.html) relates to the visible size of the mesh details. You can also think of it as distance between vertices.

So the smaller the size used, the smaller the details, which means more vertices in your mesh that are closer together.

What the size value refers to depends on the detail type selected :-

- **Relative Detail** uses screen pixels
- **Constant Detail** uses blender units
- **Brush Detail** uses the brush size